# rmarkdown - how to comment out inline code?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am writing some templates in rmarkdown, and I want to use inline r code:

```
expanded uncertainty is `r var.sd*2`
```

However as these variables (such as var.sd) are not available until blocks of code earlier are sorted out, if you try to print the report out when var.sd hasn't been defined you (of course) get an error.

I want to keep the code in the document but commented out, so that the report author can uncomment it when they have calculated var.sd.

I can't see a way of commenting the code out which prevents R interpreting the inline code.  I've tried putting into a YAML block (with # on each line) and also surrounding with

Neither of the following work

```
---
expanded uncertainty is `r var.sd*2`
---

<!--
expanded uncertainty is `r var.sd*2`
-->
```

The R inline code keeps getting interpreted and therefore throwing an error.

Is there another way of commenting this out and hiding from R ?

Comment: Are you saying you want to have an option where all inline code can be calculated or skipped depending on (for example) a setting in the YAML for the markdown document? Or just to suppress evaluation of certain inline code, depending on whether the value has been defined or not?

Comment: Isn't it expanded uncertainty is `r #var.sd*2`

Comment: A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1: just wanted to stop inline code being evaluated.  The solution from  dmi3kno and hrbrmstr below is what I needed.

Comment: I've edited the OP to explain what I was trying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
---
output: html_document
---

This is inline running code `r nrow(mtcars)` with more text

This is inline commented code `r #nrow(mtcars)` with more text
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I needed . Thanks.